# flatten ruby hash into array with keys removed

Tags: ruby

Is there a quick way to flatten a hash into an array with the keys removed?

```
h={:at => [10, 20], :width => 100, :height => 200}
```

and result to:

```
[[10, 20], 100, 200]
```

Comment: sorry. accept mean click on the check-mark icon? Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is a built-in hash method: `h.values`

Answer (score 5):

This is pretty easy:

```
h.values
```

If you want it in a particular order you'll need to do some more work.